# Running single file.tex (Titlepage, Abstract etc.) - classic thesis template

Tags: templates, classicthesis

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a single file.tex (Titlepage, Abstract etc.) which is in the folder "FrontBackmatter" https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis?lang=en.

For example, in the case of Titlepage.tex, I tried to run it with the following code in ShareLatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%*******************************************************
% Titlepage
%*******************************************************
\begin{titlepage}
    %\pdfbookmark[1]{\myTitle}{titlepage}
    % if you want the titlepage to be centered, uncomment and fine-tune the line below (KOMA classes environment)
    \begin{addmargin}[-1cm]{-3cm}
    \begin{center}
        \large

        \hfill

        \vfill

        \begingroup
            \color{CTtitle}\spacedallcaps{\myTitle} \\ \bigskip
        \endgroup

        \spacedlowsmallcaps{\myName}

        \vfill

        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{gfx/TFZsuperellipse_bw} \\ \medskip

        \mySubtitle \\ \medskip
        %\myDegree \\
        %\myDepartment \\
        %\myFaculty \\
        %\myUni \\ \bigskip

        \myTime\ -- \myVersion

        \vfill

    \end{center}
  \end{addmargin}
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: You probably chose the hardest one to 'run' as it contains so many commands defined elsewhere - look at all these `\my***`. But yes, compiling separate files should be possible *as long as* you have the proper preamble. I suggest you read some intro material on LaTeX.

Comment: Hello @PhilipPirrip, I commented the lines in which there is \my..., but it still does not work.

Comment: addmargin and includegraphics come from other packages,  remove them too (you'll be left with nothing, though)